# How can i access BIOS in sony vaio?

Tags: windows-7, sony-vaio, android-studio, software-activation, sony-vegas

I use a Windows 7 Ultimate Sony Vaio VPCEA12EN. I tried every single known method to access the BIOS, but none of them seems to work.

I've tried pressing the assist button, holding <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F3</kbd>, <kbd>escape</kbd> and <kbd>delete</kbd> buttons too. I've even tried to turn off fast boot options and that also didn't work.

How can I access the BIOS?

Comment: Sometimes just holding the key does not register as it being pressed. You need to either press it at the right time or repeatedly tap the relevant key. F8 or F12 are also sometimes used to get into the firmware.

Answer (score 1):

This is from the manual of your laptop:

```
1 Turn on the computer.
2 Press the F2 key when the VAIO logo appears.
The BIOS setup screen appears. If the screen does not appear, restart the computer and press the F2 key several times
when the VAIO logo appears.
```